# Playwright Dependency Installation error in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, server, updates, 22.10

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 x64 in Digitalocean droplet.
When i try to the step to install playwright dependency, it keeps getting an error.

```
root@ubuntu-openai-v1:~# playwright install-deps
Installing dependencies...
Ign:1 http: //mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:2 http: //mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease                                          
Ign:3 http: //mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease                                        
Err:4 http: //mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu kinetic Release                                                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.21.29.13 80]
Err:5 http: //mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release                                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.21.29.13 80]
Hit:6 https://repos-droplet.digitalocean.com/apt/droplet-agent main InRelease             
Err:7 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.21.29.13 80]
Hit:8 https: //repos.insights.digitalocean.com/apt/do-agent main InRelease
Ign:9 http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease  
Err:10 http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' no longer has a > Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http: //mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Failed to install browser dependencies
Error: Installation process exited with code: 100
```

May I know whats the solution and how to have playwright installation successfully in my Ubuntu os in digitalocean?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Your issue is because the release is EOL.  After a release goes EOL, mirrors are free to *drop* support, and the main archive is moved. Your errors are a result of the EOL being reached and thus what occurs after i having occurred. Warnings of the release are published 6 weeks prior & again at EOL, though you can check with your system (`ubuntu-security-status` at any time and get details whenever you wish).

Comment: I see, sorry i am new to this. Thank you for the feedback. Then i need to find a way to have the 22.04 lts.

Comment: You've not mentioned what product you're using (Ubuntu 22.10 Server? Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop etc), but either way Ubuntu releases have an QA-tested & supported path to newer releases; 22.10's only path was to Ubuntu 23.04 with details provided here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LunarUpgrades) though given you're EOL you may also need to use the EOLUpgrades link I provided earlier.  For Ubuntu Desktop systems you can non-destructively re-install, which allows you to go forwards & backwards though there are complications with going backwards (*best avoided for newbies*)

Comment: I am using the Ubuntu 22.10 Server in digital ocean

Comment: There is no *supported* or *quality assurance* tested way to go backwards on a Server install, outside of reverting the system from backups (ie. self-managed approaches). Desktop installs have more choices as all desktop configs are stored in $HOME which is untouched via re-install; many Server apps store configs in system directories which are wiped via re-install (*thus configs lost*) meaning the *release-upgrade* to newer release is the expected option.